# Is there a package to create an rmarkdown table with separate sections with headers mid-table? (preferred pdf output)

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I'm creating a document with `rmarkdown`, ultimately for pdf output.

I'd like to make a table that has multiple sections with subheadings (title, abstract, introduction etc.) such as the table below

[image]

I've made the following so far, but I'd like to have the vertical lines present apart from the heading rows("Title", "Abstract" etc):

```
{r prch}

pc = structure(list(`Section/topic` = c("\\textbf{Title}", "Title", 
"\\textbf{Abstract}", "Structured summary"), `Item No` = c("", 
"1", "", "2"), `Checklist item` = c("", "Identify the report as a systematic review, meta-analysis, or both", 
"", "Provide a structured summary including, as applicable, background, objectives, data sources, study eligibility criteria, participants, interventions, "
), `Reported on page No` = c("", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

pc%>%
  kbl(longtable = T, escape = F,  booktabs = T)%>%
  column_spec(1, width = "8em")%>%
  column_spec(3, width = "20em")%>%
  column_spec(4, width = "6em")%>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("repeat"))
```

[image]

Comment: I feel like package **gt** function `tab_row_group()` does what you want, although I think it is usually done on tables that look slightly different than your example. See the documentation with examples [here](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_row_group.html) plus the last code example [in this section of the intro article](https://gt.rstudio.com/articles/intro-creating-gt-tables.html#the-stub). I'm sure other table packages can do this but I happened to have seen it in **gt** more recently. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a huxtable-based solution. (My package.)

```r
library(huxtable)

ht <- tribble_hux(
  ~ "Section/topic", ~ "Item no", ~ "Checklist item", ~ "Reported on Page No",
  "Title"          , ""         , ""                , "",
  "Title"          , "1"        , "Identify..."     , "", 
  "Abstract"       , ""         , ""                , "",
  "Structured summary", "2"     , "Provide..."      , ""
  # et cetera...
) 


# using the pipe from 4.1.0...

ht |> 
  set_header_rows(c(2, 4), TRUE)                |>
  merge_across(c(2, 4), everywhere)             |>
  style_header_rows(bold = TRUE)                |>
  set_all_borders(brdr(0.4, "solid", "grey70")) |>
  set_background_color("grey97")                |>
  set_background_color(1, 1:3, "grey90")        |>
  set_col_width(c(0.2, 0.05, 0.55, 0.2))        |>
  set_font("cmss")                              |>
  quick_pdf()
```

[image: PDF output]

Comment: Thanks. So is the only way to do this to write the contents of the table in the code chunk? I prefer to create the content in excel, then `read_excel`

Comment: Sure, so use `read_excel()` and then write to your preferred package. But, if you want to edit excel directly, you are better off using `openxlsx` for a simpler round-trip.